# OpenJPA with Oracle - NullPointerException while creating the EntityManager

Tags: jpa

I am new to OpenJPA. When I tried to write a sample program with OpenJPA and Oracle, I am getting a NullPointerException while creating the EntityManager.

Sample program is

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testjpa");
        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction userTransaction = em.getTransaction();

        userTransaction.begin();
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setFirstName("Charles");
        customer.setLastName("Dickens");
        customer.setCustType("RETAIL");
        customer.setStreet("10 Downing Street");
        customer.setAppt("1");
        customer.setCity("NewYork");
        customer.setZipCode("12345");
        em.persist(customer);
        userTransaction.commit();
        em.close();
        entityManagerFactory.close();
}
```

persistence.xml is

```
<persistence-unit name="testjpa">
    <provider>
        org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
    </provider>
    <class>sample.jpa.entity.Customer</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="oracle(DriverVendor=oracle)" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="xxxxx" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="xxxxx" />
        <property name="openjpa.Log" value="SQL=TRACE" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Stacktrace is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at sample.jpa.main.TestJPA.main(TestJPA.java:16)
```

This is happening at

```
EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: If you run this from within an application server like tomcat or glassfish there might be some useful information in the logs. Like if it cannot connect or cannot find the jdbc driver.

Comment: Updated the details. I am not using any application servers. Trying with a console application.

Comment: Application server is irrelevant; you get a log from any JPA implementation WHEREVER you're running it from. You try to create an EMF and it is NULL at that line, so use the log to tell you why

Answer (score 0):

Like Eelke told you already: You have to post the exact stack trace. There is no chance to start debugging this without the stack.

I also hope that his whitespace behind "Persistence" in your code snippet is just a typo:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence .createEntityManagerFactory("testjpa");
```

Sebastian

Comment: Have you set up OpenJPA via Spring or what kind of environement are you using to initialize / load the Factory? ... Usually the persitence.xml is surounded by: <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">, it seems your file is rather incomplete. ... Also a stack trace contains more then 1 line of code. A stack trace is the complete Exception with the whole context not just one line of it.

Comment: The blank before dot will not do any harm - except to your aesthetic impression.